# Remove a bitmap from the screen when I click on the bitmap(Android)

Tags: android, bitmap, surfaceview, android-bitmap

I am drawing a bitmap in screen with surfaceview now I want remove it from the screen when ever I click/touch on the bitmap. How I can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your mainActivity to get touch coordinates:

```
(...)

int touchX, touchY;
boolean touch = false;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) 
{
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) 
    {
        touchX = (int) event.getX();
        touchY = (int) event.getY();
        touch = true;
    }

    return false;
}

(...)
```

and use this for your bitmap:

```
(...)

if(mainActivity.touch) 
{
    if( (mainActivity.touchX > bitmapX) && (mainActivity.touchX < bitmapX + bitmapWidth) &&  //
        (mainActivity.touchY > bitmapY) && (mainActivity.touchY < bitmapY + bitmapHeight) )      //touch detection for your bitmap                                                               
    {
        bitmap.recycle();  //I think this is what you want
    }    
}

if(!bitmap.isRecycled()) //using a recycled bitmap will cause an error
{    
    yourCanvas.drawBitmap(...);
}

(...)
```